# Whats the correct way to move a character through the scene? or: How to properly setup physic system in this scenario

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I ask this because my character is not colliding with the scene objects. I have a terrain and some cubes with BoxCollider. But the character (with RigidBody and CylinderCollider) walks through them.

```
#pragma strict

var movSpeed:float = 5f;
var rotSpeed:float = 150f;

function FixedUpdate ()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.eulerAngles.y += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Ok, the problem was that I forgot to uncheck 'is kinematic' flag in RigidBody component. That solved the colision issue, but now the character starts to slide over the flat terrain (without any input) after colliding with a BoxCollider and never stop. Why?

I don't know how to properly set up my character and the scene objects with the physic system.

Comment: Can you post your current code for moving?

Comment: When you uncheck the 'isKinematic', all the physic rules start to apply. If you character has a rigidbody, and lets say he is on a slope, he WILL start to fall down. This same logic applies in real life: If you are on the side of a mountain, you are going to fall off!

Comment: @GastonClaret yes.. but my terrain is flat. :( I can move the player ok.. but when he collides with a boxcolider it starts to slide and never stop.